# Exact coordinates from ios app

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3

I'm creating a tracking application and ios application is the front end to gather the coordinates. Issue is my ios application is not giving the exact path followed. Im using this code to gather coordinates

```
    locationMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
    locationMgr.delegate = self
    //locationMgr.allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled(1.0, timeout:100)
    locationMgr.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationMgr.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically=false
    locationMgr.distanceFilter=1
    locationMgr.startUpdatingLocation()
```

I'm using coordinates gathered upto 8th decimal point such as 34.98776555
but Out put is not  straight one that I followed. Please help[image]

Comment: have you tried with kCLLocationAccuracyBest

Comment: Yes vishal. I used that also but did not worked. You can see the path in attached pic

Comment: Show your code used for drawing..

Comment: hi iphonic, My javascript code is tested and  it's very lengthy code to paste it here. I think I need to get the exact value of coordinates. Please suggest your view

Comment: Its in the drawing you must be drawing curves not straight lines, check that..

Comment: Hi iphonic, See some coordinates are out of white line in pic. Path is not the issue actually the coordindates that are coming out of the white way. i walked on only the white way

Answer (score 0):

GPS Positioning typically has an accuracy of 1-5 meters. There are additional factors that can reduce the accuracy further.

As per the excerpt from the following website : [How Accurate is the GPS on my Smart Phone?](https://communityhealthmaps.nlm.nih.gov/2014/07/07/how-accurate-is-the-gps-on-my-smart-phone-part-2/)

> For any GPS to work the antennae needs a clear view of the sky. Users of smart phones will frequently be in “urban canyons” or indoors. This is where WiFi and cellular network positioning become necessary. Both of these methods are used by smart phones as indoor positioning systems. The phone will use a hybrid approach, using all three methods to locate you. These other two technologies aren’t nearly as accurate as A-GPS, but can still locate you sufficiently to find the closest vanilla latte!
>
> Generally WiFi positioning is more accurate than cellular network
>   positioning. It uses wireless access points and measures the 
>   intensity of the received signal from one or more networks to find the
>   position. Interestingly it doesn’t require your device to be WiFi
>   enabled to work.
>
> Cellular network positioning triangulates your position based off of
>   nearby cell phone towers. Phone companies have precise locations for
>   their cell towers, which when combined with signal strength can be
>   used to approximate your location. Both of these techniques are
>   dependent on overlapping signals from either access points and
>   cellular towers. Therefore they’re more accurate in urban settings.

CLLocationManger has an attribute called horizontalAccuracy which you can use to ignore points if they aren't accurate enough as per your requirements.

```
 public func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation){

    print(newLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    print(newLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    print(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy)
}
```

A GPS point which is off by just 1-2 meters will cause that point to get plotted off the road. From my experience getting pinpoint accuracy will be difficult and there is nothing that can be done about it.

Comment: Thanks Joyson for your valuable suggestion. Thanks a lot Again